# Store SockJS connection on redis

Tags: node.js, websocket, sockjs

I need to offload connections from the node server to redis, so I could update (and restart) the node server on a live system. Then pull the connections back from redis into node. Is this possible with SockJS connections?

Comment: I don't see how this would be possible with *any* networking connection.

Comment: I thought RedisStore for socket.io allowed to do this. I might be wrong.

Comment: That uses Redis to pub/sub messages between multiple `socket.io` instances/servers, but not the actual network connections.

Comment: Ok, if this is not possible you can add it as an answer :)

Comment: Let's just wait and see if anyone comes up with an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you restart your node server all your connections will be lost and your clients will be disconnected, there is no way to store the connections to reboot a server.

Comment: If the server restart-cycle completes before the next heartbeat arrive, previously connected clients will reconnect to same server. I think its ***possible***.

Comment: but the session state will be gone for all the connections i think, correct me if im wrong.

Comment: reconnecting to the same server would be unlikely to happen since nowadays all web applications runs multiple instances. so something else has to be done.

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion (don't know if it still on time):

There is no way you can store networking connection on wherever (it not serializable in any way, since it is based on OS resources).  But you can store on Redis (or any other storage mechanism) all relevant user session state, indexed by an user id of any kind.

In order to recover from a server reboot (or crash), the client could reconnect and given that it knows the user id, it can be reattached to the session state.

If you have any kind of fail over mechanism, or if the reboot process is short enough, your users will feel nothing but a little freezing on communication, if any.

I hope this can help.

Regards.

Heleno

Comment: This is the approach I went for :)

Comment: this should be the accepted answer since it's the closest to reality ( :